# Can we use $F_{\rm net} = ma$ for fictitious force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

For instance, in a non-inertial frame of reference, the net force of an object in a circular motion = (Centripetal force - centrifugal force) = 0. 
So, my question is...
Can the net force = centripetal force - centrifugal force = mass * acceleration?

Or the fictitious force (centrifugal force) is already mass * acceleration in the inertial frame of reference?

Comment: You got it all wrong. You cant subtract the two forces. Centripetal force is the actual force that acts on a body performing circular motion. Centrifugal force is the pseudo force experienced by it in its own frame. (and their value is equal). Earlier I also used to be confused between the two forces. And Yes you can use F = ma for a pseudo force. In case of centripetal force the acceleration is towards centre and so is the force

Comment: @MitulAgrawal That is incorrect. For uniform circular motion the centripetal force is always present no matter which frame you use. If you move to a rotating frame then the centrifugal force is also present.

Comment: @AaronStevens So, can we use net force = (centripetal force - centrifugal force) = ma?

Comment: Yes @AaronStevens it is always present and my bad should have mentioned that. I meant to say we use that while solving numericals in respective frames.

Comment: Yes. When I have time I'll make an answer if no one else has.

Comment: @AaronStevens Thank you for answering my question again!

Comment: Newtons Laws of Motion will only hold in non-inertial frames if the pseudo-force (fictious force) is taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in uniform circular motion, in the reference system that comoves with the object, $F_{centrip}-F_{centrif}=ma=0$.

In a non-inertial system with pseudoforces, you add the pseudoforces and actual forces, to calculate mass*acceleration. In fact the pseudoforces were introduced for this same purpose, to make the second newton law "valid" in non-inertial systems. Without the introduction of pseudoforces the second law is not longer valid in a non inertial reference  system.

Comment: Any example to illustrate this equation when ma is not equal to zero?

Comment: When the two forces are not equal, say $F_{centrip}>F_{centrif}$, you have, in the radial direction: $F_{centrif}-F_{centrip}=ma_{radial}$, so the object starts to accelerate towards the origin of coordinates. Because now the object is moving (radially) in the non-inertial frame, then a tangential coriolis force will appear and create a tangential force: $F_{coriolis}=ma_{tangential}$, and the path will not be a straight line but more like a spiral towards the center